# Including Javascript playwright library for browser navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playwright

In an already existing web project with Laravel and React, I have installed playwright packages with npm.

> npm init playwright@latest -- --ct

This file is the playwright-ct.config.js located in the . directory of my project.

```
// @ts-check
const { defineConfig, devices } = require('@playwright/experimental-ct-react');

/**
 * @see https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration
 */
module.exports = defineConfig({
  testDir: './',
  /* The base directory, relative to the config file, for snapshot files created with toMatchSnapshot and toHaveScreenshot. */
  snapshotDir: './__snapshots__',
  /* Maximum time one test can run for. */
  timeout: 10 * 1000,
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: 'html',
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on-first-retry',

    /* Port to use for Playwright component endpoint. */
    ctPort: 3100,
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },
    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    },
    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
    },
  ],
});
```

However, I attempted to include playwright in my app.jsx file with

> import {test, expect} from '@playwright/experimental-ct-react'

but it failed completely. What would be the best practice to do so ?